# Hygieia - Creation of dashboard is failing

Tags: mongodb, dashboard, hygieia

I'm working no setting up Hygieia dashboard.

Hygieia: https://github.com/gigaaks/Hygieia

Trying both approaches of setting it up locally or using Docker based installation/setup.

I'm successfully able to get mongoDB, it's API, UI modules up and running. Hygieia main login screen comes up fine. I successfully created the login user and able to log in.

At this point, I have mongoDB running, API, UI pieces running and it's time to create a CAP One / Split Dashboard (templates provided by Hygieia). When I provide the values for creating a new dashboard, it's throwing the following error in the API logs on the server (vagrant/VirtualBox instance) OR within the Docker's container.

What I found was there are lots of issues in this project's module where things are not correct i.e. database name in one module is dashboard, in other module it's dashboardb and in other, it's expecting dashboarddb. I fixed those issues in my github repo/project and initiated a pull request which is approved and will be merged. The following error though, tells my that Hygieia's UI piece is NOT sending a parameter what the API piece is expecting while trying to create a dashboard (in mongoDB). The parameter is "type" and as UI (Hygieia GUI) is not sending it (as per their latest code in GitHUB), the API is failing throwing an error saying that type variable value is passed as NULL. I found the same when I tried **POST** operation by sending the same *JSON RestAPI* query using **Postman**.

Due to this, I'm currently not able to create a dashboard and start using the collectors provided by Hygieia out of the box (for Stash, GitHub, Jenkins, SonarQube etc).

Has anyone of you have faced or found a workaround for this error/issue?

```
2016-04-01 02:40:40,357 WARN  c.c.d.rest.RestApiExceptionHandler - Bad Request - bind exception: 
org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'dashboardRequest' on field 'type': rejected value [null]; codes dashboardRequest.type,NotNull.type,NotNull.java.lang.String,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [dashboardRequest.type,type]; arguments []; default message [type]]; default message [may not be null]
    at com.capitalone.dashboard.rest.RestApiExceptionHandler.handleMethodArgumentNotValid(RestApiExceptionHandler.java:55) [api.jar!/:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.java:156) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) [spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) [spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was coming due to that fact that I used Hygieia modules docker images built locally using Maven (mvn clean install ; mvn docker:build) but for the UI module, as I was getting an error message, I cherry picked that image from captial one/hygieia-ui image. For some reason, it didn't work and was showing the above error (as there could be API level changes).

I had to run the following to get Hygieia dashboard up and running in local machine:

```
git config --global --unset-all url.https
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
npm config set prefix /usr/local

sudo npm install --color=false; sudo npm install -g bower gulp; sudo npm install bower install

mvn clean install; mvn docker:build

gulp serve
```

Now, everything is working as expected for creating dashboard (PS: You have to create mongo db database first using mongo command line as shows in Hygieia's documentation).

npm -g option will install bower and gulp globally. without -g, it'll also install the same locally. Global values actually refer the local values.

For docker based solution, I just used docker-comopose file and got it up and running.

```
NodeJS(node) version: v5.10.0
NPM (Node pkg mgr)  : 3.8.3
Bower version       : 1.7.9
Gulp  version       : [08:18:42] CLI version 3.9.1,[08:18:42] Local version 3.9.1,
Maven version       : Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T16:41:47+00:00)
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)
Java  version       :
```